# How do I nest this React component in another React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node-modules

Kind of embarrassing, since I worked as a React developer for over a year.  But the system was set up when I came in, and when I created new components I just followed the syntax for the existing components and everything worked.  But trying to do even simple React stuff on my home system has been really challenging.  I'm not sure the problem is in my syntax, but maybe in my javascript environment.

Here is a simple thing that works:

react-test.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>react-test-2</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>

    <script src="React_Components/AAA.js"></script>

    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
          const domContainer = document.querySelector('#react-container');
          const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(domContainer);
          root.render(React.createElement(AAA));
      });
    </script>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="react-container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

AAA.jsx

```
function AAA(){
    return (<div>AAA</div>);
}
```

The .jsx files are in React_Components_JSX, which is watched by the Babel preprocessor, which makes analogous .js files in React_Components. When I navigate to the html page, it renders the expected "AAA" on the page.

Now I'm just trying to nest another component inside the AAA component.  So I update the file AAA.jsx and create a file BBB.jsx, something like the following (although I have tried various syntaxes hoping to make this work).  I am expecting to see a webpage that renders "AAABBB".

AAA.jsx

```
import BBB from '../React_Components_JSX/BBB.jsx';

function AAA(){
    return (<div>AAA<BBB/></div>);
}
```

BBB.jsx

```
export default function BBB(){
    return (<div>BBB</div>);
}
```

The main error I am getting is "Cannot use import statement outside a module".  Which I know explains the problem, but I don't really understand what that means on a fundamental level, as far as how I have to set my application up.

Comment: You're going to struggle trying to use JSX and ES6 modules outside of a bundler / build system. Is there a reason you're using React via CDN links?

Comment: I would strongly encourage you to use a modern build tool like Vite (https://vitejs.dev/guide/) and follow the startup guide for React development.

Comment: @Phil I want to convert an existing web app into a more modern configuration, splitting it into a React front end and PHP API.  The React docs say 'With a few lines of code and no build tooling, try React in a small part of your website. You can then either gradually expand its presence, or keep it contained to a few dynamic widgets.'  So my plan was that, to start with one div on the main interface that would be populated by React, and then gradually move more pieces of the interface into the React setup until the whole interface was built by React.

Comment: @Phil Just to make clear, the code I posted is just a small test case replicating the same issues I am having on the actual app.

Comment: Well you need Babel to handle the JSX and you need to use modules in order to use `import`. You'll have a much easier time using a build system

Comment: Don't use React via the CDN. Yes, it's an option, but it absolutely isn't a good one. If you've already got Node.js installed on your computer, just run this terminal command to create a React app: `npm create vite@latest`

Comment: @KeeganTeetaert  Why vite and not create-react-app?

Comment: @BowenTravis here is an article https://semaphoreci.com/blog/vite